# Possible values of the complex arcsinh inverse of sinh

Tags: complex-analysis

We are given the definition of the principle value of arcsinh as
$$PV\sinh ^{-1}(w) = \mathrm{Log}(w + PV\sqrt{w^2 + 1})$$
where $PV\sqrt{w^2 + 1}$ is the principal value of the square root function (when $k=0$).

My notes say:
"It is easy to check that $\sinh (PV\sinh ^{-1}w) = w$ but it need not be true that $PV\sinh^{-1}(\sinh z) = z$.
What are the possible values of $PV\sinh^{-1}(\sinh z) - z$?
I'm unsure how to do this, as I did try letting $w:= \sinh z := \frac{e^{z} - e^{-z}}{2}$ to no avail.

Comment: Example: $\sinh^{-1}(\sinh(2i))=\sinh^{-1}(\sin(2)i)=(\pi-2)i,$  check on WolframAlpha with `arcsinh(sinh(2*I))` More striking:
$\sinh^{-1}(\sinh(\pi i))=0!$

Comment: So it looks like the possible values of $PV\sinh ^{-1} ( \sinh z ) - z$ are in $i\pi \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Rather $\sinh^{−1}(\sinh(z))+z \in i\pi\mathbb{Z}$ as shown by another example $\sinh^{−1}(\sinh(1+2i)= -(1+2i) + i\pi$ and by the plot from Wolfram `arcsinh(sinh(x+y*I))+(x+y*I)`

Answer (score 1):

Note that we have

$$\begin{align}
\text{PV}\sinh^{-1}(\sinh(z))&=\log\left(\sinh(z)+\text{PV}\sqrt{\sinh^2(z)+1}\right)\\\\
&=\log\left(\sinh(z)+\text{PV}\sqrt{\cosh^2(z)}\right)\\\\
&=\log\left(\sinh(z)+\cosh(z)\right)\\\\
&=\log(e^z)\\\\
&=z+i2n\pi
\end{align}$$

for any $n\in \mathbb{Z}$.

---

Note that without the principal value, the square root $\sqrt{\cosh(z)}$ is multivalued.  Then, we have

$$\sinh^{-1}(\sinh(z))=\log(\pm e^z)=z+in\pi$$

for $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ as reported by Wolfram Alpha.